# APPLE TESTFLIGHT: how to specify a single, internal tester group for the latest build, instead of all internal test groups

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Everytime I upload a new build, TESTFLIGHT tab selects all the groups as it did for previous uploads.

How can I edit the groups for a build (under GROUPS column) so there is only one specific group?

Can't figure out how to edit the default groups that it auto-adds.

Comment: It shouldn't auto add external groups... Are you using maybe Fastlane to upload the app? In there, you can predefine groups. So might be the culprit?

Comment: I am only using Xcode archive >> Distribute >> Upload.  I have no control anymore of the Groups of testers.  I will have to delete all Internal Testing groups and start again.

Answer (score 1):

For internal groups, you have the option for Automatic or Manual distribution via the Enable automatic distribution checkbox. You can select this option when you create the new internal group and one more thing This value cannot be changed after the group has been created.

[image]